# How to pass today's date and time as argument in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running python script using ansible.

Here is my playbook -

```
- name: Run python script 
  command: python Test.py -StartDate 2020-10-01T00:00:00 -EndDate 2020-11-05T00:00:00
  register: result
- debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
```

I want this playbook to use EndDate as todays date when I run script. How can I use latest date and time in same format I have written every time I run script without having to change manually every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the `T00:00:00` is always fixed, you could declare a variable using the lookup plugin, see an example below the `exec_date` variable and the modified `command` task:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    exec_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d') }}T00:00:00"

  tasks:
  - name: print
    debug: var=exec_date

  - name: Run python script 
    command: "python Test.py -StartDate 2020-10-01T00:00:00 -EndDate {{ exec_date }}"
    register: result
  - debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
```

If you want to pass the current time too instead of a fixed `T00:00:00`, you could use the below:

```
  vars:
    exec_date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') }}"
```

cheers

Comment: FWIW, keep in mind that "[*lookups*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine". In most cases, this might be not only fine but required. But, this might also create problems if the exact local time on a remote host is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Q: ***"How can I use the latest date and time ... ?"***

A: Given the script below

```bash
shell> cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

If the granularity by seconds is sufficient the most efficient way is using the function [*strftime*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times)

```yaml
    - name: Run script
      command: >
        {{ playbook_dir }}/test.sh '{{ "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"|strftime }}'
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
  result.stdout: '2023-05-09 00:09:29'
```

If you need microseconds use Ansible facts variable [*ansible_date_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)

```yaml
    - setup:
        gather_subset: date_time
    - name: Run script
      command: "{{ playbook_dir }}/test.sh {{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro }}"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
  result.stdout: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.023295Z'
```

---

Notes:

- The dictionary *ansible_date_time* will be also created by '[*gather_facts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html)*: true*' when a playbook starts.
- If needed there are other attributes in the dictionary

```yaml
  ansible_date_time:
    date: '2023-05-09'
    day: 09
    epoch: '1683583769'
    epoch_int: '1683583769'
    hour: '00'
    iso8601: '2023-05-08T22:09:29Z'
    iso8601_basic: 20230509T000929023295
    iso8601_basic_short: 20230509T000929
    iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.023295Z'
    minute: 09
    month: '05'
    second: '29'
    time: 00:09:29
    tz: CEST
    tz_dst: CEST
    tz_offset: '+0200'
    weekday: Tuesday
    weekday_number: '2'
    weeknumber: '19'
    year: '2023'
```

- The variable *ansible_date_time* will not be updated automatically when a playbook runs. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.023295Z'
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.023295Z'
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.023295Z'
```

- Run module [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) to update the variable *ansible_date_time*. For example,

```yaml
    - setup:
        gather_subset: date_time
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
    - setup:
        gather_subset: date_time
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
    - setup:
        gather_subset: date_time
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:29.845384Z'
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:30.390135Z'
  ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro: '2023-05-08T22:09:31.059892Z'
```

- The function *stftime* updates the date and time automatically

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
    - wait_for:
        timeout: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
    - wait_for:
        timeout: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: '2023-05-09 00:26:58'
  msg: '2023-05-09 00:27:00'
  msg: '2023-05-09 00:27:01'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is working :-)